# Returning a shuffled array after submit, but in the same order each time

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that stores a range of numbers between 0 and 5 and when the page loads the array is shuffled. When a form with drop-down options gets submitted I want the array to return in the same sequence as before.

```
$game=range(0,5);
shuffle($game);
echo implode ("," , $game);



<form method ="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
  <select name="values">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
 </select> 
<input type="submit" name="game" value="Play">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 0):

If you seed the random number generator with the same value each time using `srand()` or `mt_srand()` then it will "randomize" it the same way:

```
$game=range(0,5);
srand(2016); // whatever value you like, could easily be just 1
shuffle($game);

print_r($game);
```

Comment: hey thanks for that, i am not familiar with most of this but when does that get undone or unset?

Comment: At the end of the script.  But using the same seed number makes shuffle() shuffle the same way each time its run.